# C# linq2sql selecting multiple columns

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

I am struggling to select multiple columns in the carCheckouts table. I just want the startMiles and endMiles from one row that I know the pk of. Is my linq statement correct? if so how do I turn b.startMiles and b.endMiles into usable variables after? Thanks

```
var m = (from b in db.carCheckouts
where b.pk == primaryKey
select new {b.startMiles, b.endMiles});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current query returns an `IQueryable` of an anonymous type - but it sounds like you want a *single* item:

```
var m = (from b in db.carCheckouts
where b.pk == primaryKey
select new {b.startMiles, b.endMiles}).Single();
```

Now you can use the properties of `m` just so:

```
Console.WriteLine("Start Miles:"  + m.startMiles);
```

Comment: Understand that the Single() call will only return without error if there is EXACTLY one result of the query. This should be valid for a search on a PK you know exists, but in other circumstances there may be no such record matching the filter, or many. SingleOrDefault will return without exception if there are 0 or 1 items; FirstOrDefault will work in cases of zero to many results.

Answer (score 2):

You've turned m into an anonymous type (actually m will be an IQueryable<> of that anon type) that can be used anywhere inside the scope it's declared.  Anon types were added to allow something like this so you don't have pre-create a type that would hold these values, you create the type on the fly.

If you want to only have 1 and not an IQueryable you can do .FirstOrDefault or just .First to give you the 1 instance of that anon type.

Answer (score 2):

```
var m = (from b in db.carCheckouts
where b.pk == primaryKey
select new {b.startMiles, b.endMiles});

double totalMiles;

foreach(var item in m)
{
    totalMiles = item.endMiles - item.startMiles;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

select new {b.startMiles, b.endMiles}).FirstOrDefault();

on your linq statement